# Google Speech To Text V2. Expected resource location to be global, but found

Tags: speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I use client libraries for java version: 26.26.0, I follow the examples from the documentation for speech to text V2, I want to create a recognizer according to the documentation: location "europe-west4", model "chirp" and language code "bg-BG". but I always get an exception: "INVALID_ARGUMENT: Expected resource location to be global, but found europe-west4 in resource name.", Even if I manually create a recognizer through "https://console.cloud.google.com/speech" I can't use it

I tried to change the endpoint to "europe-west4-speech.googleapis.com", with other users it seems to work, but when I change it, I can't login with a service account

I tried to create recognizer through "https://console.cloud.google.com/speech"
I tried to change the endpoint to "europe-west4-speech.googleapis.com"